# Python script to iterate through mysql tables and alter tablespace

Tags: python, mysql

I'm in the process of restoring a mysql database. I am trying to loop through the mysql tables and discard each table's tablespace so i can replace it with the old .ibd file.  What is the proper Python code to use to accomplish the

> `ALTER TABLE <table> DISCARD TABLESPACE`

for each table in the database using a Python script?  I'm using Python 3 with mysql 8.0

Thanks

~brohjoe

Comment: what does discard tablespace do? is it the same as drop table?

Comment: Discard tablespace deletes the existing .ibd file (which contains the actual mysql data) from the table.  It does not delete the table structure (which is the .frm file).  I think MySQL 8 does not use both  .frm and .ibd files together anymore.

Answer (score 1):

The first you need for connect to a database is a thing named **connector**, on your case you need a connector for language python and version **8.0 of MySQL** on this case you need download the **connector** from here: https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/python/

For **install** a connector: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-installation-binary.html

When you have installed it, you can start to make **connection to database and other things** via this documentation references: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-examples.html

Comment: Thank you Deon.  How about the script to loop through each table and perform the ALTER TABLE <table> DISCARD TABLESPACE for each table in the database?

Comment: If you know MySQL this isn't problem, with ``.execute("command")`` function you can run MySQL commands! An possible solution about ``DISCARD TABLESPACE`` is here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/212808/how-can-i-fully-remove-a-tablespace-from-mysql

Comment: I appreciate your help Deon.  I read that link and like the last person stated on the site, a simplistic moving of .ibd files don't work in every case. I still have to make the sql call to discard the tablespace then import the old .ibd file.  Anyway, I worked on the code and I have an approach I'm trying to implement, but the issue is using the results of one cursor.execute is needed in a second cursor.execute and the code dies when the second execute is executed.  (I will post in a new SO question).